# How to git commit & push as another user

Tags: git, github

I've heard it is possible to push a commit as another user but unsure how is that possible or done, as an example where i saw it was https://github.com/jayphelps/git-blame-someone-else/commit/e5cfe4bb2190a2ae406d5f0b8f49c32ac0f01cd7
i tried using

```
git commit -am "message" --author="Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>"
```

but that's just as commit name, the history in github will still show as yourself, any way to do what happened in that commit url i sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the --author flag worked but just that webhooks in the app i was using showed up old usernames, this was really a dumb question I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't push for another person if you don't have proper credentials or computer setup with git.

If you are interested in keeping two accounts in the same machine take a look at

[this link](https://medium.com/@therajanmaurya/git-push-pull-with-two-different-account-and-two-different-user-on-same-machine-a85f9ee7ec61)

Comment: Yea but how does that "pretending to be linus" commit works I'm mostly curious about that

Comment: It shows you everything right there, some guy made an obvious scam account that would fool newbies as a way of warning people not to trust that things  mean what they would in a world where everyone is trustworthy.  He might have even gotten away with making his GitHub name "Linus Tȯrvalds" and that might have gulled the inattentive along with the gullible, that and more determined attempts are why there's GPG.

Comment: But isn't github usernames per user as in can't use a used name, plus the thing exactly links to the real user

Comment: See? You didn't notice the different o.  Zoom in until you see it.  There's other ways to make things computers regard as different, because they are, even less visually distinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody who really cares exactly who's vouching for a commit will demand a GPG signature on that commit, and if there's a legal requirements they'll demand specific signatures on the signing keys.  I don't care whether you're really "Free TNT" so I don't demand signatures on your posts, I just care that your posts make sense.  The tradeoffs are the same with pushed code: what you have to do to convince the upstream repo to accept your pushes is up to them, and you should ask them about it.